# Create a counting variable which I can use to group my unemployment data in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I have data as below where i created the variable "B" with the function:

```
index <- which(Count$unemploymentduration ==1)
Count$B[index]<-1:length(index)

ID unemployment B
1    1          1 
1    2          NA
1    3          NA 
1    4          NA 
2    1          2 
2    2          NA 
2    0          NA
2    1          3
2    2          NA
2    3          NA
2    4          NA
2    5          NA
```

And i want my data in this way and have no real idea how to get it like this. 
Thought of an "if-function" but never used one in R.

```
ID unemployment B
1    1          1 
1    2          1
1    3          1
1    4          1
2    1          2 
2    2          2 
2    0          2
2    1          3
2    2          3
2    3          3
2    4          3
2    5          3
```

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `library(zoo)`

```
library(zoo)
Count$B <- na.locf(Count$B)
```

But, this can be created directly without using an 'index'

```
Count$B <- cumsum(Count$unemployment==1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Thats exactly that what i wanted.